# Velocity measurement in relativistic perspectives

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, perception, time-dilation

I understand the precepts of relativistic time dilation, but I'm looking to nail down the local perception of velocity in each frame. My question is threefold:

1. Given two observers $A$ (rest frame) and $B$, if $A$ observes $B$ traveling
   away from starting point $A$ at $V=2c/5$, does $B$ perceive a different
   value for $V$ based on dilation, or the same, based on it's local
   frame?
2. If it is the same (which is my assumption), how does this integrate
   with the predicted experience of $B$ from the point of view of $A$
   (which I also assume would seem to act as a multiplier on perceived
   velocity due to dilation)?
3. As a further silly notion, does it change if at some point $B$ stops
   and proceeds to return to $A$ at the same previous velocity? My assumption is it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value B sees for V depends on which combination of frames they use for their reference.  If they look entirely in their own frame and are moving at constant velocity, they can't tell what velocity they're moving at.  If they observe A, they will see A moving with a velocity V.

If however, they look at preset distance markers in A's frame and use the B frame measurement of time, they will see something called the proper velocity.  Brehme referred to this as speedometer velocity[1].  It's the velocity that corresponds to how far B will have travelled in A's frame over the amount of time B experienced.  The expression for proper velocity is $v_\tau = \gamma v = sinh(\phi)$, where $\gamma = \sqrt{1-V^2/c^2}$, and $\phi$ is the rapidity of B's frame which is related to V by $V/c = tanh(phi)$.

This brings us to the third question.  What happens if B stops and returns to A.  Let's say that B slowed to a stop and started back up again in the opposite direction with a constant acceleration.  The change in proper velocity of B while accelerating is $\Delta v_\tau = \gamma v = c sinh(\frac{a\tau}{c})$, where $\tau$ is known as the proper time as measured in B's frame.

References

1. Flynn, R.W., Spacecraft navigation and relativity, AJP, 53, (1985), 113
   http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.14092
2. Rindler, W., "Hyperbolic Motion in Curved Space Time", Phys. Rev. 119 2082{2089 (1960).
3. Rindler, W, "Special Relativity", Interscience Publishers, 43 (1944)

Comment: The answer I gave to this question is the conventional interpretation. Personally, however, I believe you are absolutely right - local measurement of the velocity does differ from measurement made by a stationary observer (because v' is not the measurement of stationary observer's relative movement, but the measurement of the object's movement made by the moving observer). Therefore I up-vote your answer.

Comment: apologies for the late comment. Am I correct in the assumption that it also holds true that if the point of observation changes, but not the distance markers or time referent that the above formulae remain unchanged?

Comment: @VoidSinger, I'm not entirely sure I understand the full intent of your question.  If the point of observation changes within a frame, you should be fine, and the formulas should be unchanged.

Comment: I should have specified from B to A, but working through it it look like it does. the important part was the perception of others remote experience rather than the actual experience

Answer (score 2):

1. No, $B$ will perceive the same value of $v$ for $A$. According to special relativity, it is impossible for $A$ and $B$ to determine which one of them is moving from their reference frames.
2. Both will have the same experience from their perspectives. $A$ will see $B$ contracting along the direction of motion and its clock moving slower, and vice versa.
3. If $B$ starts going in the opposite direction with velocity $v$, nothing will change except the perceived direction of motion from both of their reference frames and hence the direction of contraction.

I am not sure if this is all what you were asking. Let me know if I misinterpreted something.

Comment: in 2, based on the dilation of B as observed from A, would A's perception predict B to observe V as .4c/dilation_fraction_of_A?

I'm not trying to violate special relativity, just trying to explore the discontinuity of perception.. I realize that considering from each frame individually gives the correct answer, just trying to nail down loose ends from a single pespective, and see how they fit into the overal scheme.

Comment: Their perceptions would be the same. I do not understand you completely.

Comment: working _only_ from A's perspective, My assumption is it would seem that it would view V as (.4c/observered_dilation) if A were to make a linear guess at B's perspective without the benefit of the theorem. Obviously that's an incorrect answer based on the theory, which treats both perspectives as equal. is there another transform that describes this discontinuity, or rectifies it aside from treating both perspectives as equal?

Comment: No, both observers will perceive V to be the same. There is no discontinuity, your assumption is wrong. I found this http://www.rafimoor.com/english/SRE.htm, give a read to the part about reference frames. Also, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: I don't appear to be explaning myself well. the discontinuity I'm aiming at isn't between both observers, but rather between the observation and the reality... the theory predicts the actual reality (both observers see the same thing)... taking only the single observer A in point 2, they observe dilation of B ergo their observation would also predict a difference in velocity (in the time component) local to B (even though none exists from B's perspective). The difference seems to be born out by the linked page w/ differing perception of event order re: woman on train & man on the ground...

Comment: So I think you are asking how the time dilation and other relativistic effects create subjective realities according to an observer's perception but causes no discontinuity in the objective reality. I have wondered that many times myself and the conclusion that I always come to is that there is no objective reality. Every observer has a different version of what is reality, or what they see or experience in the Universe.

Comment: Thanks yes, that's were I was looking. apologies for not being able to describe a better test case, if you coud add a note to that effect for #2, I'd be pleased to accept that as the answer.

Comment: I don't really have anything else to add because I don't really know what exactly is confusing you in that point. There is no objective time, or perception.

Comment: just something to the effect that individual frames observations are subjective to their local frame of reference, since that secton was about single perspective (rather embarrassed I hadn't come across a version of the train description before, thanks for that, it does distill it much better than my own question)

Comment: Yes, every individual's reference frame will be subject to that individual's relative velocity with some other reference frame or observer. If there is a third person $C$, he will also have his own perspective and will not experience the effects that $A$ and $B$ are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

The Special Theory of Relativity gives us no direct transform equation for velocity for strictly two-body situations. There is only the velocity addition formula $s = \frac{u + v}{1 + (vu/c^2)}$, which can be "simplified" by assuming that $s$ equals zero.

However, the sub-section [Principle of relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Galilean_and_Einstein.27s_relativity) in the entry on derivation of Lorentz transforms in Wikipedia states that there is no privileged frame of reference, and explicitly says that you should assume that the apparent velocities perceived by persons A and B have the same value, yet opposing directions. Therefore:$$v = - v'$$
 (which is obviously quite puzzling though, since the variables x and t change under the transforms in inverse proportion - hence time dilatation and length contraction - and therefore it seems the values for v and v' should differ).

And yes, you are right, reversing the direction of the movement changes only the directions of the perceived velocity vectors.

Comment: "The Special Theory of Relativity gives us no transform equation for velocity (at least I did not find any)." — It does. It's known under the (IMHO unfortunate) name "relativistic addition of velocities" (the term is because under Galilean transformations velocities transform by addition).

Comment: Addition of velocities is about two movements in respect of the third, considered stationary, frame of reference. This case is completely different, as only one of the reference frames is moving, while the other is considered stationary. Therefore we are not adding velocities here, because there is only one velocity - either the A person/object is moving in respect of B or B is moving in respect of A.

Comment: Being stationary just means moving at velocity $0$.

Comment: Being stationary means not moving at all.

Comment: "Not moving at all" makes no sense in relativity, since there's no such thing as absolute rest. The "stationary frame" is just the frame of some inertial observer which you have *chosen* to call "stationary" (another unfortunate convention, as your comments clearly demonstrate). Especially, given that observer A is not accelerated, it is a perfect choice for the "stationary" observer.

Comment: There is also no such thing as absolute v=0.

Comment: Yes, but there's $v=0$ relative to an observer. Which is your "missing" second velocity, as each observer is at rest (i.e. $v=0$) relative to himself.

Comment: Basically, the "addition theorem" tells you the answer to the question "if observer B moves with velocity $v$ relative to observer $A$, and an object moved with velocity $u'$ relative to observer $B$, then what is the velocity $u$ of that object relative to observer $A$? That is, how does $u'$ in inertial system $B$ transform to inertial system $A$? The answer being, of course, $u = (v + u')/(1+ vu'/c^2)$. Note that the fact that the transformation is in the unusual direction (B to A, rather than A to B) is also due to the unfortunate "addition" interpretation.

Comment: The equation for the addition of velocities was derived for a situation when a passenger of the train moved within the moving train. If you assume one of the velocities equal zero, you will not get the reversal of velocity direction.

Comment: On the other hand, the fact that the velocities have the same value is not a result of the calculation based on the addition of velocities theorem. The value was **assumed the be the same** from the beginning and used for derivation of Lorenz transforms. It is a kind of axiom actually.

Comment: It of course doesn't matter whether you imagine one observer being at rest relative to earth and the other relative to a train; all that matters is the velocity of one observer relative to another. The question which leads to the sign reversal is: What is the velocity $u'$ in B's frame so that the velocity in A's frame is $u=0$ (that is, the velocity of A in A's frame). Inserting into the "addition formula" and solving for $u'$ gives $u'=-v$. And yes, this doesn't invalidate your more basic argument (that's why I upvoted your answer). But that doesn't change the fact that …

Comment: … the "addition theorem" *is* the transformation formula for velocities (which therefore exists). That, and only that, is what I claimed. Also note that to derive the Lorentz transformations, you use that the speed of light is constant; the "sign change property" is already true for Galilean transformations.

Comment: OK. Let's put it this way. There is no direct transform for 2-body (ref. frames) relative velocity. We don't need it, as they are assumed to be the same. And yet, we need a transform for time and length in 2-body situation, because they are not assumed to be the same. Hence, we have 2-body transforms for time and length, but not for velocity. On the other hand, as there is no velocity transform for 2 bodies, we need one (the addition formula) for a 3-body situation, if we assume their relativistic values will change. It can be shown, however, it is coherent with the assumption for 2-bodies.

Comment: I hope this statement: "There is **no direct transform for 2-body** (ref. frames) relative velocity." settles our dispute. :)

Comment: Well, the relevant case here is not $u=0$ or $v=0$, but $s=0$ (using your symbols).

Comment: Well, I never played with this equation to solve for two body case. I guess you want to retain the reversal of velocity direction? I don't have the time right now, but at first first glance it seems that if you assume $s=0$, the term $1 + uv/c^2$ might cause some difficulties. Are you sure this equation will actually reduce to $u=-v$? Instinct says it should, but instinct also says there should be no relativistic addition of velocities, if there is no transform needed for two bodies ...

Comment: Since $|u|<c$ and $|v|<c$, $1+uv/c^2 \ne 0$, and thus we can just multiply the equation with it, giving the simplified equation $u+v=0$ and thus $u=-v$. That's simple algebra (and anyway, if it would *not* give that result, relativity would clearly be inconsistent). And your instinct is misled by that word "addition" (and I don't really get that "no transform needed" anyway, to be honest; A's velocity is transformed from $0$ to $-v$, and B's velocity from $v$ to $0$).

Comment: Sure :) You can also say that $s=0$ only if $u+v=0$ (because if the denominator equals zero s would be undefined). I'm actually busy with some altogether different thing ...

Comment: Please take extended discussions to chat.